# How to create cache for multi Threads to access?

Tags: c#, multithreading, caching, architecture, binary-tree

I have a service that spins up 50+ agents.

Service => creates lots of agents in separate threads. The agent needs to load 1 of 2 binary tree's created dynamically, but this needs to be reloaded often.

Is their a way I can cache the binary tree's, for all the agents to utilize, instead of each one having to load its own instance? would that need to happen in the service level? ie. service creates 2 binary trees. service creates agents. Agents now can access it.
I have never cached anything before. I would also need a mechanism to rebuild this binary tree with new data, yet not break the agents who are trying to access it.

Im dealing with an incredibly high volume of data processing. ie. 50,000 records a second needing to be compared. Im trying to avoid having each agent store their own binary tree, as it would eat up memory. I am fine doing instead of caching, sql light solutions, or other in memory options.

Comment: Some kind of lazy refresh mechanism sounds like it could work. Depends how out of date the cache can be. What code do you have so far? An alternative solution (if the data is going into a SQL database anyway) is to rely on the database itself, and just pass the information in and have it work out the processing on the server, without keeping anything in memory. 50 threads sounds ridiculous anyway: presumably you can move to `async` `await` and use normal threadpooling

Comment: Are these trees being modified by the agents? Or are they all getting the same things and producing an output independent of one another?

Comment: Are you creating your own home-made binary trees, or you are using the [`SortedDictionary<K,V>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2) class? Also are these trees frozen/immutable after creation?